# MongoDB to Elasticsearch using PySpark

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, pyspark

I want to integrate my MongoDB collections to Elasticsearch using PySpark. I have the connection string of my MongoDB, but I don't know how to structure my code or specify some parameters. Could someone give me the code example on creating this task? Though I'm still new in this area, I've tried to read some documentation, but I found myself stuck on some parameters and still don't get the clear flow of this task. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In Spark you can work with RDDs or DataFrames.
RDDs are not structured and are the older Spark API.
To work with RDDs you need to use `MapPartition`, `ForEachPartition` and alike.
DataFrames are structured and enable using Spark SQL functions which are similar to ANSI SQL.

MongoDB enables a per-document schema. Spark DataFrames requires a uniform schema per DataFrame.

If your collection has a uniform schema for all the documents per collection (depends on whatever inserted the data), you can manually (via code) create a Spark schema definition (`pyspark.sql.types.StructType` in PySpark). For examples look at Spark documentation of StructType, DataType, StructDef, FieldType, ArrayDef, DictDef, StringType etc.

If your MongoDB collection does not have a uniform schema, you will need to use RDDs, then convert it to a uniform schema via `MapPartition` so that you use this uniform schema for the Elasticsearch index.

You can use Spark SQL to read DataFrames from Mongo via pyspark with: `spark_session.read.format('mongo').option('uri', 'mongodb://uri.to.mongo.goes.here').schema(schema=spark_schema_goes_here)` and similarly write using `df.write.format('mongo').option('uri', uri).mode(write_mode_eg_append).save()`

I can't remember the Elastic syntax, however, it is similar and there the definition is schema per index. Try searching for Spark in MongoDB site and in Elasticsearch site to find more details.

It is possible to create the Elastic index definition automatically from the Spark schema definition, I once did this, however, do not have the code.

Comment: thanks for your explanation! I found this site https://simplernerd.com/migrate-mongo-elasticsearch/ then I think this maybe the possible solution. But, I still got confused on how to configure the Elasticsearch config. Can you or someone else help me to understand that code?

Comment: @sam.marhaendra You can ask in that site and you can try and debug it yourself and ask about the parts you don't understand in a new question here. Include the code itself, no links though.